# Compile error: label not defined

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that looks for something from the master sheet in column D such as "1x Daily" or "2x Month" (as well as others). If the cell matches a Sheet name, it gets pasted into that sheet. The problem is each row from the Master sheet is unique and therefore cannot be repeated on each sheet. Every time I run the code, it adds the rows again, so I end up with something like this

Coubourn, Stephen|A|201|Q4hours
Eudy, Donna      |A|202|Q4hours
Potts, Betty     |A|203|Q4hours
Coubourn, Stephen|A|201|Q4hours
Eudy, Donna      |A|202|Q4hours
Potts, Betty     |A|203|Q4hours
Coubourn, Stephen|A|201|Q4hours
Eudy, Donna      |A|202|Q4hours
Potts, Betty     |A|203|Q4hours

Below is what I have so far for this code I am trying to make, however, it isnt working. Im receiving the error message "Compile error, label not defined" on the line that says "On Error GoTo SetFirst"

```
Dim cell As Range
    Dim cmt As Comment
    Dim bolFound As Boolean
    Dim sheetNames() As String
    Dim lngItem As Long, lngLastRow As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet, shtMaster As Worksheet
    Dim MatchRow As Variant

    Set shtMaster = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Vitals Data")

    ReDim sheetNames(0)
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sht.Name <> shtMaster.Name Then
            sheetNames(UBound(sheetNames)) = sht.Name
            ReDim Preserve sheetNames(UBound(sheetNames) + 1)
        End If
    Next sht
    ReDim Preserve sheetNames(UBound(sheetNames) - 1)

    For Each cell In shtMaster.Range("D1:D" & shtMaster.Cells(shtMaster.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
    bolFound = False
        MatchRow = Application.Match(cell.Offset(, -3).Value, sht.Range("A:A"), 0)
        If Not IsError(MatchRow) Then
            shtMaster.Rows(cell.Row).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=sht.Cells(MatchRow, 1)
        Else 
            On Error GoTo SetFirst
            lngLastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
            On Error GoTo 0
            shtMaster.Rows(cell.Row).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=sht.Cells(lngLastRow, 1)
        End If

        If bolFound = False Then
            For Each cmt In shtMaster.Comments
                If cmt.Parent.Address = cell.Address Then cmt.Delete
            Next cmt
            cell.AddComment "no sheet found for this row"
            ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False
    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
        End If

    Set sht = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Compilation fails because there is obviously no label SetFirst. Where is the execution supposed to go when the error is raised in the line between `On Error GoTo SetFirst` and `On Error GoTo 0`?

Comment: Im not sure, I am brand new to this. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: I will probably be able to suggest if you could explain what exactly your code should do. What's the purpose of all this subroutine? Also, your code is not complete, it starts with `Dim ...` however should start with `Sub ...`

Comment: @Alexey ha, good eye! The indentation threw me off, my brain subconsciously replaced `Dim` with `Sub` and ignored the rest of the line!

Comment: @S Rock It's OK using the code from the answer I gave you here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351143/change-code-so-that-it-doesnt-populate-more-cells-just-replaces-with-changes , but using it here and **Not** marking as "Answer" - not so much

Comment: @shairado I wouldnt have asked another question if it worked. I have 0 knowledge of macros and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> On Error GoTo SetFirst
> ```

This instruction tells the VBA runtime, in case of an error, to jump straight to the `SetFirst` subroutine to handle the error.

When you compile the code, VBA sees that there's a conditional jump to that `SetFirst` label, but there's no such label to jump to, so VBA can't resolve `SetFirst` and compilation fails.

Not sure what your intent is, but things would typically look something like this:

```
    Exit Sub

SetFirst: '<<<<<<<< that's your line label
    Debug.Print "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Err.Clear
    'comment-out or remove before distributing:
    Stop
    Resume 'step through (F8) here to jump back to error-causing instruction
End Sub
```

Line labels / subroutines are locally scoped, meaning you can't `GoTo`-jump to a line label that's located in another procedure. If you have `SetFirst` in another procedure and intend to jump there in case of an error, you have some serious spaghettification in process.